# Compressed MP3 files show in Thunar but not in Dolphin. Why?

Tags: files, thunar, dolphin

This morning I tried to compress my MP3 files with lame and did that. But after that, whatever target name I give to the compressed files are not being listed in Dolphin.

However, these compressed files show up both in Thunar and the terminal. See the attached screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you refresh the Dolphin window?

Comment: Yes many times . one more thing they appeared back after I reopen that dolphin after five minutes or so .

what's the matter with the delay .